# Cake PeekXml does not "ignore" namespace

Tags: cakebuild

Is it a bug or per design that xmlns attribute is not ignored?

(cake version 0.33.0)

---

With an Xml like so (a too simplified nuspec file):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd">
    <metadata>
        <!-- Continuously updated elements -->
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </metadata>
</package>
```

I do a naÏve call
`var x = XmlPeek( "my.nuspec", "/package/metadata/version/text()" );`
ad get the result `x==null`.

So I specify the namespace like so:

```
var settings = new XmlPeekSettings{
    Namespaces = new Dictionary<string, string> {{ 
        "ps", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2010/07/nuspec.xsd" 
    }}
};
var x = XmlPeek( "my.nuspec", "/ps:package/ps:metadata/ps:version/text()", settings);
```

and get the result `x==3.0.0` I anticipated.

Answer (score 5):

It is not a bug.

To ignore the namespace you can use namespace agnostic xpath such as [`local-name()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/local-name):

```
var x = XmlPeek( "my.nuspec", "/*[local-name() = 'package']/*[local-name() = 'metadata']/*[local-name() = 'version']/text()");
```

or if you have only one `version` node:

```
var x = XmlPeek( "my.nuspec", "//*[local-name()='version']/text()");
```

but be careful with documents with large numbers of elements - this can become very slow.